# Using array of Action() in a lambda expression

Tags: c#

I want to do some performance measurement for a method that does some work with int arrays, so I wrote the following class:

```
public class TimeKeeper
{
    public TimeSpan Measure(Action[] actions)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            action();
        }
        return watch.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

But I can not call the `Measure` mehotd for the example below:

```
var elpased = new TimeKeeper();
elpased.Measure(
    () =>
    new Action[]
        {
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000)
        });
```

I get the following errors:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Action[]' because it is not a delegate type
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'
```

Here is the method that works with arrays:

```
private void FillArray(ref int[] array, string name, int count)
{
    array = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Array {0} is now filled up with {1} values", name, count);
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a Lambda expression? Can't you just call `Measure(actions)`?

Comment: I tried that but I still get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'`

Comment: Just a quick note, why are you using a void function with a ref parameter, rather than returning an array?  In general, it's not good practice to use ref parameters if you're not returning anything.  In your case, you'd have to change your code to use Func<> instead of Action<>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Measure` expects its first argument to be an `Action[]`, not a lambda that returns an `Action[]`. And the actions array expects you to pass delegates, while you are in fact *calling* `FillArray`.

You probably want this:

```
elpased.Measure
(
    new Action[]
    {
        () => FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
        () => FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
        () => FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000)
    }
);
```

Comment: I tried that but I still get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'`

Comment: No you didn't try that. Look carefully.

Comment: @cicada hmm I copy pasted exactly, I get 3 errors `; expected`, I tried to place semiclones but no success!

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action'

This array initializer is expected to fill out the array with `Action`s returned by the `FillArray` method which is not the case.

```
new Action[]
        {
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000),
            FillArray(ref a, "a", 10000)
        });
```

Change the `FillArray` accordingly to return an `Action` instead of `void`

Comment: Yes this answers only one part of the question not all of it.